# Magento: catalog & product images not uploading

Tags: php, magento

For some reason catalog images are not uploading properly, with no error messages or anything in ./var/log/exception.log or ./var/log/system.log or /var/log/httpd/magento/error.log - simply it just seems to ignore the image file.

Perhaps relatedly, catalog_product_entity_media_gallery doesn't seem to be updating at all when I upload product images, hence uploaded images show in the front end but not in the back end at all. On re-save they are removed.

I'm unsure where to start with debugging, been looking around for a while with no luck!

This just started happening a few days ago after importing a few products. Before then it was working fine.

Comment: how does your importer work? Is it UPLOADING them via http, or ftp? Are all images affected or just certain images(configurable/simple)? What does your firewall say? Is this also happening when you upload images directly from the backend? What ERP or CRM are you importing from? So many questions...

Comment: I'm not using an importer, just adding products through the admin backend. Uploading products - image appears in correct directory, appears on frontend but isn't there on the backend. Catalog images never get uploaded to tmp or the correct place.

Comment: are your folders writable? Oh and try another browser and update your flash. Disable the cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by updating to the latest version of Magento Community Edition.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when importing products and not assigning them to the admin store (store id 0).

for example, if you load a product for store 1 (default store) and then save images to this store's version of the product, then they will not be visible in the admin area.

images must be assigned to store 0's version of the product for them to be visible in the admin.

I am guessing you have created your products and assigned only to store 1, and then saved the procucts images to this.

I would try re-importing your products, and not setting a store id before saving, this will automatically add them to the admin store for you and your issues should vanish :)

Comment: I'm adding them through the admin backend, not using an import function or my own code. Looks like Magento isn't setting any database values for store 0... any thoughts?

Comment: Have you imported the products first though or were they also added in the admin?

Comment: if the products were added via importer they may not have added the product -> store link

Comment: it first happened after an import, now just products added normally won't hold their images in the back end

Comment: sounds like your importer has messed something up, is it a custom script or a module?

Comment: I'm not using an importer now, just uploading products manually. I was using data profiles before.

Answer (score 0):

David, before you start changing permissions and looking for more complex reasons for the problem try this:

Use either Internet Explorer or Chrome and you should be right.

I had the same issue where I could not upload images using the Magento admin to product pages. What I found was simply that I was using Firefox and something to do with Flash or Java was causing the issue.

It is working fine for me now.